# Protractor elements are not identified after login page

Tags: angularjs, protractor

My code works for identifying all elements on login page but, once after login button is clicked, on the second page none of the elements are getting identified in the code.

Below is my js page

```js
 describe('Login page', function() {
 var username= element(by.model('username'));
 var password= element(by.model('password'));
 var resetbutton=element(by.css('btn.btn-
     warning.bigbutton.customButtonStyle'));
 var submitbutton=element(by.css('.btn.btn-
  success.bigbutton.customButtonStyle'));
  
 beforeEach(function() {
  browser.get('http://localhost:3000');
  browser.sleep(1000);
      });

it('Enter username and password:', function() {
 username.sendKeys("abc");
 password.sendKeys("abc");
 submitbutton.click();
 browser.sleep(1000);
 console.log("test successful");
});

it('second page',function() { 
 var input = element(by.id('pendingTab'));
browser.wait(function(){
    return input.isPresent();
}, 10000).then(function(){
    input.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    });
```

Angular page looks like

```html
<div class="box-body">
         <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
           <ul id="messageListTab" class="nav nav-tabs" ng-init="setStatus('New')">
               <li id="tab3" class="active" ng-class="{active:true}">
               <li id="tab2">
                       <a id="pendingTab" ng-click="setStatus('Pending')" 
                      data-toggle="tab" data-target="#incidentTab">
Pending  
                </a>
</li> </ul></div></div>
```

Inside Tab2 I am trying to find click on pending tab. What could be the problem and why protractor is not able to identify any elements on second page?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "they're not being identified"?  Is it throwing an error etc?

Comment: yeah. error thrown is  "unable to locate element".. . I have verified that locator exists and not inside frame,but still i get the same error for any elements inside second page.